# Passing a kwarg to a wrapped function when wrapper has same arguement

Tags: python

Lets say a have a function that wraps other functions, like map for instance, whose signature looks like:

```
def map(func, iterable, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now lets say I have a function x whose signature is:

```
def x(a, b=None, c=0, d=100, iterable=list())
```

If I try to call

```
map(x, [1,2,3,4], iterable=[5,6,7,8])
```

I'm going to get a TypeError because the map function has been passed the "iterable" argument twice, even though one of them is intended to the map function and the other to be passed through to the x function.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Sounds like you need more descriptive argument names

Comment: Sure, but you don't get a choice over argument names when you didn't write the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great place to use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial). This function returns a partial, which will behave like a func allowing map to work, but also will allow you to change keywords ahead of time. In this case all you should have to do is `map(functools.partial(x, iterable=[5,6,7,8]), [1,2,3,4])`

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify your problem, I have a function which takes at least one normal argument and then key word argument

```
def fun(x, y, **karg):
    print x, y, karg
```

We can't use x or y in karg. Why?
Python support another feature "matched by name while calling a function", Arguments don't have to be at same position. We can always call fun as

```
fun(y = 12, x = 6)
```

So when we use normal argument name as key word argument, this is clearly ambiguous for python.
There can be some hack to solve this But it'a better to use different name in key word arguments.